# How to upload photo from gallery in Android to a website with Dropzonejs?

Tags: javascript, android, dropzone.js

Im using dropzonejs to upload photos to my website. The problem is, when I click dropzone to upload, it won't show 'Gallery' as an option as seen in this image :

[image]

How to add Gallery as an option?

Comment: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/397

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a matter of fact, in order to show the gallery app to android user, your `<input>` element must have two properties explicitly defined:

**type** which is `file` and **accept** which could be, as mentioned, `image/*` (or any image-related mime-type)

A way to achieve this is by instantiating the Dropzone object yourself rather than relying on the dropzone class of a `<form>` :

```js
// removes the magical auto discovery of dropzone forms
Dropzone.autoDiscover=false;

// add accepted mimeTypes options (comma separated string)
// myDz is the camelCased version of the id of the element that will be "dropzoned"
Dropzone.options.myDz = { acceptedFiles: 'image/*'};

$(function(){
  // instantiate dropzone on element with #my-dz id
  // if no action in the form or applying dropzone on a non form (ie a div),
  // you should at least pass the url in an object as the second parameter
  dz = new Dropzone('#my-dz' /*, {url:"/my-upload-url"}*/); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ctn">
      <h1>Test Dropzone Android</h1>
      <form action="#" method="post" class="dropzone" id="my-dz"></form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could find some useful (although a little dated) information here: [Uploading photos from mobile web app](http://simonguest.com/2012/07/06/uploading-photos-from-mobile-web-applications/)

PS: Thanks to [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701856/drskullster) who helped me to gather those informations

Comment: Many thanks, but do note that firefox on android doesn't do that yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with plupload and I fixed with:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]')[0].setAttribute("accept","image/*");
```

Answer (score -3):

You can edit dropzone.js file
and after line 540: `_this.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("type", "file");` 
Insert code: `_this.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");`

Comment: I do not think that hacking the source code of a lib is a good practice